# How to use the value element to pass values internally from $form to $form_state['value']

Tags: 7, forms

I have a form and i want to pass some values without user see them.

At the beginning i was using the default values:

```
$form['field_devis_lien_fiche']['und'][0]['value']["#default_value"] = t("@path",array("@path" => $path));
```

It was working fine but it's not the behavior i wanted because all the user could see the value.

So i buy "pro drupal 7 developpment" and at page 283, he describe the **element value** and i think this is what i have to use.

```
$form['title'] = array(
 "#type" => 'value',
 "#value" => $titre,
); 
$form['field_devis_lien_fiche'] = array(
 "#type" => 'value',
 "#value" => $path,
);
```

The $form['title'] works fine but all my other fields trigger an error.

```
Warning: array_values() [function.array-values]: The argument should be an array in _field_filter_items() (line 517 of ***/modules/field/field.module).
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in text_field_validate() (line 119 of ***/modules/field/modules/text/text.module).
Notice: Undefined index: #language in locale_field_node_form_submit() (line 405 of ***/modules/locale/locale.module).
```

When i want to edit my content type, my value doesn't exist.

So i tried another solution with the hidden element:

```
$form['title'] = array(
 "#type" => 'hidden',
 "#value" => $titre,
); 
$form['field_devis_lien_fiche'] = array(
 "#type" => 'hidden',
 "#value" => $path,
);
```

In spit of the fact that my hidden fields are created when i inspect the form, i have the same error again (with array_value problem)

i don't understand why it's works for the title field and why it's not working for my other field. And i don't understand too, why i have an error with the hidden field as they appears well when i inspect element with firefox.

Do i have to create a validation function because of my element value? Maybe i have forgotten a step...

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you'll need to set the type of the correct element to `value`, and that isn't what you've got at the moment. Notice how you use:

```
$form['field_devis_lien_fiche']['und'][0]['value']["#default_value"]
```

To access the field the first time round (which you've confirmed to be working). Logically then, if you want to change the same field to a `value` type, you need to do so on the same element:

```
$form['field_devis_lien_fiche']['und'][0]['value'] = array(
  "#type" => 'value',
  "#value" => $path,
);
```